# Why am I getting "could not establish connection to network" in C# compact framework?

Tags: c#, .net, http

Note: The below username and password is 100% correct...please help me

```
public static bool DownloadFile(string url, string destination)
    {
        bool success = false;
        int i = 0;

        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = null;
        System.Net.WebResponse response = null;
        Stream responseStream = null;
        FileStream fileStream = null;



        try
        {
            i = 1;
            request=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://retfsoftware.com/SiddhPrj/TimeClock Biopad.exe/");

           //request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";




            request.Timeout = 100000; // 100 seconds
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usernmae", "password");
            //request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            response = request.GetResponse();

            i=2;
            responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            fileStream = File.Open(destination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

            // read up to ten kilobytes at a time
            int maxRead = 10240;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[maxRead];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            int totalBytesRead = 0;

            // loop until no data is returned
            while ((bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, maxRead)) > 0)
            {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            // we got to this point with no exception. Ok.
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            // something went terribly wrong.
            success = false;
            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message + (i));
        }
        finally
        {
            // cleanup all potentially open streams.

            if (null != responseStream)
                responseStream.Close();
            if (null != response)
                response.Close();
            if (null != fileStream)
                fileStream.Close();
        }

        // if part of the file was written and the transfer failed, delete the partial file
        if (!success && File.Exists(destination))
            File.Delete(destination);

        return success;
    }
```

PLease find the above code and assist me

Comment: Can you establish a connection using a web browser to the same URL with the same credentials and on the same machine in the same network? That would help isolate if this is a network problem, system configuration issue, or a software issue.

Comment: Yes..!

When i establish connection thorugh web browser with same name and password it getting opend in same network and same machine. IT is ftp server.
I want to download file from my ftp server in Compact framework CE 6.0..!

Above code is not running please help me out..!
If u have another way please let me know

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is still having this problem, I found a few solutions for my case.

- *If you are using an emulator*: Use tools -> device emulator manager to cradle your network connection to the emulator.
- *If you are using an actual windows mobile device*: Go to the settings -> connections app on the device, and then navigate to advanced and click on Exceptions. Here is where I added the ip for my computer/Host running a REST service for the mobile .NET CF application. The webrequest no longer threw the exception.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `FtpWebRequest` type instead. In your example you are using `HttpWebRequest` and HTTP is not how FTP servers talk to their clients. It's a different protocol.

Comment: but is is not there in namespace System.Net. I have tried to get ftp but it is not showing

Comment: @user4265170 You're on the compact framework and so it's not available to you. You will need to find a library that gives you this functionality. https://ftp.codeplex.com/ is one free example.

Comment: @user4265170 If this has solved your issue, please mark the answer as such. I'm glad I could help!